# Working with part of a query at a time

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate query which returns 10s of thousands of object results.  Is it possible to cycle through chunks of the query rather than handling the entire query at once?

Sample code:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("FROM Class");


List<Class> classList = (List<Class>) q.list();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [query.setMaxResults(int)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29) and [query.setFirstResult(int)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setFirstResult%28int%29) to page through the query.

Usually you'd write a method that displays page x of the result size where y is the number of items per page:

```
public List<Thingy> showThingies(int itemsPerPage, int pageOffest){
    // ..
    query.setMaxResults(itemsPerPage);
    query.setFirstResult(itemsPerPage * pageOffset);
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ScrollableResults](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html) from hibernate

Something like:

```
ScrollableResults results = session.createCriteria(Project.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("projectType", Constants.REINDEX.PROJECT_TYPE))
            .setFetchSize(10)
            .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

while (results.next()) {
        project = (Project) results.get(0);
```

If you are scrolling through a huge ammount of entities you should probably also *clear* your session from while to while, else you could run out of memory.

More information is to be found in the documentation [10.4.1.6. Scrollable iteration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html) and as they wrote it, you should use pagination if you don't want your connection to stay open.